# Maximal order with primitive determinant in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: determinant, finite-fields, primitive-roots, general-linear-group

The following question has come up in a facet of a current project.  Having an answer (hopefully affirmative) will help me design and test some computational simulations.

$\mathbb{F}_q$ denotes the finite field of $q$ elements and $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ its group of units.  Consider the general linear group $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$.  It is known that the maximal possible order of an element from this group is $q^n-1$, realized by Singer cycles.  (That this is an upper bound is a not-so-hard argument with Cayley-Hamilton; that it is actually achievable is where Singer cycles enter.  Thanks to Derek Holt for teaching me this.)

Given a matrix $A \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, we can ask if its determinant is a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_q$.  In case it's not, it is not hard to "modify" $A$ to make its determinant generate $\mathbb{F}_q^*$:  take your favorite primitive $\alpha$ and scale the first row of $A$ by $\frac{\alpha}{\det(A)}$.  This, of course, likely alters the order of the matrix:  there is no reason this new matrix should have the same order as $A$.  This approach is too naive for what I need.

My question is how to simultaneously optimize both situations.  That is,

> Given $n$ and $q$, must there exist a matrix $A \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for which (1) $A$ has order $q^n-1$ and (2) $\det(A)$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Some lame trial-and-error in a few small cases (low $n$, low $q$) does not exclude "yes" as a possible answer.  I've tried to argue by counting/pigeonholing, but I cannot prove this.  Here's what I tried.  The map
$$ 
\det: \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q) \to \mathbb{F}_q^*
$$
is surjective with rather large kernel $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$.  Hence each $d \in \mathbb{F}_q^*$ has $|\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|$ preimages.  At the same time, there are $\varphi(q-1)$ primitive elements in $\mathbb{F}_q$, which is also proportionally "high," each primitive having  $|\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|$ preimages.  Thus we have a pool of
$$
\varphi(q-1) \cdot |\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)| = \frac{\varphi(q-1)}{q-1} \cdot |\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|
$$
matrices in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ whose determinants are primitive. Given the asymptotics of $\frac{\varphi(k)}{k}$, these seem to make up a decent portion of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, leading me to think this is always possible. Must one of these preimages have maximal order $q^n-1$?

Is this argument salvagable or is it too crude?  Or, is it simply false?  Any arguments or counterexamples are appreciated.

Comment: I would simply select matrix $A$ to represent multiplication by a primitive element of the extension field $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ and be done with it. In that case the determinant becomes the (relative) norm. The norm map $N:\Bbb{F}_{q^n}^*\to\Bbb{F}_q^*$ is known to be surjective, so a generator of the domain is mapped to a generator of the image. Mind you, looking at the extension field is a natural way to deal with Singer cycles also.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  thank you for your comment.  I had the same thought, but I could not see the determinant.  Is there some obvious way to see this (maybe in some clever choice of basis)?  Apologies, this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: (I am familiar with the fact that the norm maps units to units, surjectively.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments to me about the question, now, once again, deleted by the asker.  I wasn't able to comment back to you there, given the OP's deletion.  I did manage to flag moderators to alert them.

Comment: By the way, my flag and whoever else flagged for moderator attention resulted in the deletion of the current account of the repeat poster of the same user, whose history you shared with in comments.  Good work!

Answer (score 3):

- For $A\in GL_n(\Bbb{F}_q)$ if $order(A)=q^n-1$ then $A$'s minimal polynomial $P(x)\in \Bbb{F}_q[x]$ divides $x^{q^n-1}-1$ which is separable so that $A$ is diagonalizable (over the algebraic closure).

  Expressing the order of $A$ in term of the lcm of the order of the eigenvalues, that is the roots of $P(x)$, you'll get that $order(A)=q^n-1$ iff the roots of $P$ have order $q^n-1$, which implies that $P$ is irreducible of degree $n$  and that the roots generate $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}^\times$.

  Letting $a$ be a root then the others are $a^{q^m},m\in 1\ldots n-1$ (Galois theory, Frobenius automorphism).

  Since $\deg(P)=n$ then $P$ is also the characteristic polynomial of $A$, therefore

  $$\det(A)=  \prod_{m=0}^{n-1} a^{q^m} = a^{(q^n-1)/(q-1)}$$

  It has order $q-1$ and it generates $\Bbb{F}_q^\times$.
- Conversely take $a\in \Bbb{F}_{q^n}^\times$ of order $q^n-1$, let $P(x)\in \Bbb{F}_q[x]$ be its $\Bbb{F}_q$-minimal polynomial and $A$ its companion matrix. Then $P$ is the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $A$ so that $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ which will have order $q^n-1$.